# connection error while using mysql_real_escape_string() in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am using mysql_real_escape_string() in php to insert data in mysql database using html php form.But on submit it is giving an error that 'Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established' but without using mysql_real_escape_string() the form is submitting properly.
my php code is

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['add']))
{
    require_once('nikhil.php');
    $bookname=$_POST['bookname'];

    $discription=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['discription']);
    $price=$_POST['price'];


    $dir='';
    $uploadDir = ''; 
    $fileName = $_FILES['photo']['name'];
    $filePath = $uploadDir . $fileName;

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"],"uploads/".$_FILES["photo"]["name"]))
    {
        $query_image = "INSERT INTO letDo (photo,bookname,price,discription,publicationName) VALUES ('$filePath','$bookname','$category','$releases','$price','$discription')";
        if(mysqli_query($con,$query_image))
        {
            echo "Stored in: " . "xyz.co " . $_FILES["image"]["name"];
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'File name not stored in database';
        }
    }
    else{echo 'File not uploaded';}
}
?>
```

Comment: Mixing mysql with mysqli!!

Comment: instead of `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['discription']);` try to use `mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['discription']);` and so on (check for others yourself).don't mix both

Comment: thanxx 'Saty' and @Anant it works....

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) if you ever forget to properly escape something. Note that `$bookname` here is not escaped, so this code is vulnerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not connecting to the database using mysql_connect, then you shouldn't be using mysql_real_escape_string. If you do, then it'll try to connect to the database on its own, using the default params in php.ini (the results of which, you're currently seeing). It looks like you're using mysqli, which is a whole different extension, and has its own escape function -- mysqli_real_escape_string. Use that instead.

Comment: ops srry i forget that i already encounter with the same problem and i solve it using mysqli but i forget it anyway. thanxx for the help.